# Android textwatcher for more than one edittext

Tags: java, android, textwatcher

In my android application, I am using text watcher for adding values of edit text where values of each edit text value is added together and displayed in a text view.. for example if first edit text value is 23 and second edit text value is 25 they both are added together and displayed in a text view ..
This application is about numerology .. in first edit text users first name is entered and in second users middle name is entered and in third edit-text users last name is taken and each letter has its own value from 1-9 so that corresponding values are added together and make it to a value between 1-9..this process repeat for all three edit-text values then the value for all three edit-text are added together and make it to 1-9 and displayed in a text-view.

I did code for this but it is working fine for one edit-text.. but when calculating together two edit-text somewhere error is happening any one please help if understood the error..

MainActiviy

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity

    {

        EditText et1,et2,et3 ;
        TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4;


        String name = "";
        String name1 = "";
        String name2 = "";

        String hname = "";

        int nameValue = 0;

        int hnameValue = 0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            //TextView for displaying results
            tv2 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tv7);
            tv3 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tv9);
            //tv2 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tv7);

            //EditText for entering names
            et1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);


            //Text change listner for first Name
            et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 

            {               
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
                {
                    //s= (et1.getText().toString() + et2.getText().toString() + et3.getText().toString());
                     //showNameValue(s);
                    // showHeartNumber(s);
                    tv2.setText(addNumbers());


                }
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int p2, int p3, int p4)
                {}
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
                {

                }   
            }); 
    }

    protected String addNumbers() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int number1; 
                int number2;
                int sum = 0;
                if(et1.getText().toString() != "" && et1.getText().length() > 0) {
                    number1 = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
                } else {
                    number1 = 0;
                }
                if(et2.getText().toString() != "" && et2.getText().length() > 0) {
                    number2 = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());
                } else {
                    number2 = 0;
                }
            name = Integer.toString(number1 + number2);

            for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
            {
                sum += letterValue(name.charAt(i));
            }
            nameValue = sumDigits(sum);

            //tvwNameSum.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
           // tv2.setText(String.valueOf(nameValue));

            return Integer.toString(nameValue);
        }


private int sumDigits(int n) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int sum = 0;

        if (n == 11 || n == 22)
        {
            return n;
        }

        while (n > 0)
        {
            sum += n % 10;
            n /= 10;         
        }

        if (sum < 10)
        {
            return sum;     
        }
        else
        {
            return sumDigits(sum);
        }
    }


    private int letterValue(char c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (c < 65 || c > 90)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        int v = (c - 64) % 9;
        return v == 0 ? 9 : v;
    }
}
```

logcat

```
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "s"
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at com.example.newnumerology.MainActivity.addNumbers(MainActivity.java:122)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at com.example.newnumerology.MainActivity$1.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:63)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7231)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7290)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:8880)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:962)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:496)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.text.method.QwertyKeyListener.onKeyDown(QwertyKeyListener.java:222)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.text.method.TextKeyListener.onKeyDown(TextKeyListener.java:136)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5385)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5204)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2609)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7205)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1920)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1395)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2370)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1847)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3701)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3651)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2818)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-04 07:07:37.920: E/AndroidRuntime(3586):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 07:07:38.310: D/dalvikvm(3586): GC_CONCURRENT freed 150K, 10% free 2692K/2972K, paused 59ms+89ms, total 542ms
```

Comment: From your stacktrace: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "s"`. You entered "s" which is not an integer. Are you restricting all EditTexts to only integer values?

Comment: No.. Actually.. my app is a numerology app.. where user will enter his names in edittext.. and its integer value is added together and displayed.. so I cant make edittext to integer

Answer (score 2):

You are converting string "s" to int. This is why you are getting this exception.

Better restrict your EditText to enter only integers

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="0123456789."
/>
```

or

```
try{
   if(et1.getText().toString() != "" && et1.getText().length() > 0) {
                    number1 = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
                } else {
                    number1 = 0;
                }
                if(et2.getText().toString() != "" && et2.getText().length() > 0) {
                    number2 = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());
                } else {
                    number2 = 0;
                }}
catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
{
  // Handle the exception here.
}
```

Comment: thanks Pillai. Actually.. my app is a numerology app.. where user will enter his names in edittext.. and its integer value is added together and displayed.. so I cant make edittext to integer

Comment: @Jocheved You are missing the point: in either case, you cannot use parseInt() on a non-integer string.

Answer (score 1):

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 

        {               
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                 showNameValue(s);



            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int p2, int p3, int p4)
            {}
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {

            }   
        });



protected void showNameValue(CharSequence s) 

    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        int sum = 0;    

        name = s.toString().toUpperCase();
        //name1 = s1.toString().toUpperCase();

        for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
        {
            sum += letterValue(name.charAt(i));
        }
        nameValue = sumDigits(sum);

        //tvwNameSum.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
        tv2.setText(String.valueOf(nameValue));



    }
```